# Django create nested model

Tags: django

I want to create a Model in which I can store the same models as for example in a folder there can be several folders.
I tried like this:

```
class Service(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField(default="")
  price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class ServiceType(models.Model):
  services_types = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceType, null=True, blank=True)
  services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, null=True, blank=True)
  name = models.TextField(default="")
```

But it didn't work. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: can you show what is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference same model then you have to use quotation 'ModelName' like this.

So your code will be like:

```
class Service(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField(default="")
  price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class ServiceType(models.Model):
  services_types = models.ManyToManyField('ServiceType', null=True, blank=True)
  services = models.ManyToManyField(Service, null=True, blank=True)
  name = models.TextField(default="")
```